# How to open a webpage and run your JavaScript on it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a webpage then insert my own Javascript into it.

I have the current code here:

```
window.location.assign('http://http://79.170.44.75/hostdoctordemo.co.uk/downloads/vpn/index.php');

document.getElementById('address_box').value = prompt("Site Address: ");

document.getElementById('go').click();
```

and what I am trying to do is:

1. Load the webpage
2. Set the address box to a value
3. Simulate a mouse click on the search button

So it loads the webpage, then searches a value it sets itself.

The problem with my current JavaScript is that as soon as the webpage has loaded the JavaScript stops working (as I expected). I have tried using the *iframe* tag to load the webpage 'within the webpage' but that did not work when obtaining the *id* and people said iframe would also not work because of the resolution difference.

**The Question: ** How do I load a webpage and run my own JavaScript code on it? Thank you!

- Matthew

Comment: is the extra `http://` in the `assign` a typo?

Comment: why dont you write your javascript inside that webpage? any particular reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're propably looking for something like [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey).

Answer (score 0):

I really can't see an easy way to do what you want.
When the browser receives a web page from a server the javascript is interpreted, and only after that, the page is presented on the screen.

So you would have to have a web page with a button or other mechanism to make a request to a web server, receive the request, save its contents locally, add your javascript code and only then "give it to the browser".